# Help With Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture and Chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to roll my own javascript application architecture based off of the recommedations by [Nick Zakas](http://yuilibrary.com/theater/nicholas-zakas/zakas-architecture/) and I am using jQuery as the base library.  I have everything pretty much working but it dawned on me that I have lost the ability to chain methods togeather since you ask the sandbox for methods using the dot notation.  Is there a good solution to this? See below for more details.

```
...register module...

sandbox.click('p', function(){..});

....
```

Each module gets an instance of the sandbox which is created when the module is registered.  The Class is just a thin piece of code that translates module requests into core actions.

```
Sandbox.prototype = {
    click : function(el,cb){
        return Core.click(el,cb);
    }
}
```

In the core I'm returning a bunch of available methods.

```
... Private members above
return {
   click : function(el, cb){
      $(el).click(cb);
   },
   ... more public methods
}
```

So currently I have no means of chaining methods together because the accessor will not have any of the other methods I want to chain to it.  If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: i would have to see how sandbox is getting created. If sandbox always returned itself, you would be able to call additional methods that are on the sandbox in the same way that you can call methods on jquery objects. That obviously wont work for ajax and getter methods  since they return values and objects.

Comment: I updated the example to use click. I started here and haven't changed on how modules are registered and given an instance of the sandbox. Warning more comments than actual code =]. http://fran.ie/magda/projects/sanbox/symbols/src/_home_framus_projects_sandbox_Sandbox.js.html

Comment: a click translating into an ajax call is bad design

Comment: @Raynos  I assumed that was a typo, originally that was ajax: function()...  Of course, i could be mistaken.

Comment: A fairly simple implementation that follows this talk fairly closely can be found here: https://github.com/aranm/scalable-javascript-architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sandbox.prototype = {
    click : function(el,cb){
        Core(el).click(cb);
    }
}
```

would become

```
Sandbox.prototype = {
    click : function(el,cb){
        Core(el).click(cb);
        return this;
    }
}
```

That results in when you call Sandbox.click(element,callback), the click event is bound and the sandbox is returned. That means you can use Sandbox.click(element,callback).click(element,callback).someOtherMethodOnSandbox();

Just make sure that all of the methods return "this" and you will be able to chain.

Comment: Your example is a little different because it uses jQuery in it but non the less it works.  Thanks!